# how to set the location and font size of the graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Now I write some code to draw the graph. However, the graph is too large, I just want to put it in the left half of the document. So how to set the font size and location of the graph?

Also, I want to change the `and-or-gate` to `diamond` or `bigoplus` in the graph like

[image]

I don't known how to draw it,would someone help me? The code below is taken from [TeXample fault tree example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fault-tree/):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.US,trees,positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
% Gates and symbols style
    and/.style={and gate US,thick,draw,rotate=90,
        anchor=east,xshift=-1mm},
    or/.style={or gate US,thick,draw,rotate=90,
        anchor=east,xshift=-1mm},
    be/.style={circle,thick,draw,anchor=north,
        minimum width=0.7cm},
    tr/.style={buffer gate US,thick,draw,rotate=90,
        anchor=east,minimum width=0.8cm},
% Label style
    label distance=3mm,
    every label/.style={blue},
% Event style
    event/.style={rectangle,thick,draw,text width=2cm,
        text centered,font=\sffamily,anchor=north},
% Children and edges style
    edge from parent/.style={->,very thick,draw=black!70},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- ++(0,-1.05cm)
            -| (\tikzchildnode.north)},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm,level distance=1.4cm,
            growth parent anchor=south,nodes=event},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=5cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
    level 4/.style={sibling distance=2cm}
%%  For compatability with PGF CVS add the absolute option:
%   absolute
    ]

  \begin{scope}[xshift=-15cm,yshift=-5cm,very thick]
%% Draw events and edges
    \node (g1) [event] {No flow to receiver}
         child{node (g2) {No flow from Component B}
            child {node (g3) {No flow into Component B}
               child {node (g4) {No flow from Component A1}
                  child {node (t1) {No flow from source1}}
                  child {node (b2) {Component A1 blocks flow}}
            }
               child {node (g5) {No flow from Component A2}
                  child {node (t2) {No flow from source2}}
                  child {node (b3) {Component A2 blocks flow}}
            }
           }
            child {node (b1) {Component B blocks flow}}
        };
%% Place gates and other symbols
%% In the CVS version of PGF labels are placed differently than in PGF 2.0
%% To render them correctly replace '-20' with 'right' and add the 'absolute'
%% option to the tikzpicture environment. The absolute option makes the
%% node labels ignore the rotation of the parent node.
   \node [or]   at (g2.south)   [label=-20:G02] {};
   \node [and]  at (g3.south)   [label=-20:G03] {};
   \node [or]   at (g4.south)   [label=-20:G04] {};
   \node [or]   at (g5.south)   [label=-20:G05] {};
   \node [be]   at (b1.south)   [label=below:B01]   {};
   \node [be]   at (b2.south)   [label=below:B02]   {};
   \node [be]   at (b3.south)   [label=below:B03]   {};
   \node [tr]   at (t1.south)   [label=below:T01]   {};
   \node [tr]   at (t2.south)   [label=below:T02]   {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please state the source of the code even if the code is free to share/copy, it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I've updated my answer, Please let me know if something like that is what you need.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thanks for your answer, sorry that I don't know if the answer satisfy, I should to accept it, and even have no idea of how to accept an answer, so sorry about it.

Comment: @sweetyBaby You're welcome. Regarding the "accepting answers" issue, no problem at all (the same happens to a lot of users). Now you know how to accept answers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below there's one possibility. The main points:

1. First the `tikzpicture` code was written (modify the code according to your needs).
2. Then, the `\resizebox` command (from the `graphicx` package) was used to scale down the `tikzpicture` width to `0.5\textwidth` (use the desired width and/or height).
3. Then the scaled figure was place inside a `wrapfigure` environment from the `wrapfig` package to allow text wrapping.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
   \usepackage{wrapfig}
   \usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

   \begin{document}

   \lipsum[2]
   \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.5\textwidth}
   \resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}[
   oplus/.style={draw,circle, text width=2.5em,fill=blue!20,
     postaction={path picture={% 
       \draw[black]
         (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east) 
         (path picture bounding box.north west) -- (path picture bounding box.south east);}}},
   block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
       text width=5em,align=center, minimum height=3em},
   decision/.style = {diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
       text width=4.5em,inner sep=0pt},
   line/.style = {draw,thick, -latex'},
   node distance=1.8cm and 1cm
   ]

   % Place nodes
   \node [block] (a) {text};
   \node [block, below of=a] (b) {text};
   \node [decision, below of=b] (c) {};
   \node [block, below left of=c,xshift=-1cm, yshift=-0.3cm] (cl) {text};
   \node [block, below right of=c,xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.3cm] (cr) {text};
   \node [oplus, below of=cl] (cla) {};
   \node [block, below of=cla] (clb) {text};

   % Draw edges
   \path [line] (a) -- (b);
   \path [line] (b) -- (c);
   \path [line] (c) -| (cl) node [near start,anchor=south] {if};
   \path [line] (c) -| (cr) node [near start,anchor=south] {else};
   \path [line] (cl) -- (cla);
   \path [line] (cla) -- (clb);

   \end{tikzpicture}}
   \end{wrapfigure}
   \lipsum[1-2]
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Comment: aha, it is exactly what I need, however, there is error said `<insert text> \par` I can not find what the problem is in the code.

Comment: @sweetyBaby I need to see the actual code you are using; otherwise, it's impossible to say where the error might be. Can you upload the code somewhere and provide a link here?

Comment: OK, however, actually I just run your code ~

Comment: @sweetyBaby my code runs OK in my system. Perhaps you are using outdated package(s)? Process the following test document: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfversion
\end{document}`. The output should print the PGF version used in your system; mine is `2.10`; if you have an older version, you will need to update PGF (and perhaps all of oyur LaTeX system).

Comment: I have updated to 2.10, it works now!!! Thanks very much :-)